# Ember data Error: the adapter's response did not have any data

Tags: ember.js, adapter, store

I just upgraded an app from Ember 1.13 to Ember 2.12.  Now my attempts to load the data store are failing.  This line:

```
return this.store.find('blog', 14);
```

generates this error:  "Error while processing route: blogs.index Assertion Failed: You made a `findRecord` request for a blog with id 14, but the adapter's response did not have any data".

But the data is arriving, and in this format:

{
    "blogs": {
        "id": 14,
        "person_id": "1",
        "access": "3"
    }
}

My adapter is specified in application/adapter.js as:

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

host: "http://localhost",
  namespace: 'api-rick'

});

Anyone know why I'm getting this error?  I think the JSON is properly formatted -- didn't have any problems before I upgraded Ember.

Later EDIT, here's relevant code:

```
//application/adapter.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

  host: "http://localhost",
  namespace: 'api-rick',

  pathForType: function(type) {
    //this so types (db table names) are singular;
    //else are pluralized in Adapter's request
    return Ember.String.singularize(type);
  }
});

//application/serializer.js
port DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
});

//pods/contact/model.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name         : DS.attr(),
});

//pods/contact/route.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('contact');
  },
});
```

//payload returned when viewed in Chrome's developer tools (contact table has only the one record):

```
{
    "contact": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bilbo the duck"
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally, here's the errors reported in Chrome's console:

```
Transition #0: contact: calling beforeModel hook
ember.debug.js:55891 
Transition #0: contact: calling deserialize hook
ember.debug.js:28573 
Error while processing route: contact Assertion Failed: You made a `findAll` request for contact records, but the adapter's response did not have any data Error
    at assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:20732:13)
    at Object.assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:32400:34)
    at assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:85626:37)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:97389:41
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73561:14)
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73576:15)
    at publish (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73544:9)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:53448:16
    at invokeWithOnError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:15377:16)
    at Queue.flush (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:15436:9)
```

Comment: How about your serializer, is it extending http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html. `find` is private method now. consider using findRecord http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findRecord

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't specified a serializer since the RESTAdapter was the default adapter in Ember 1.13.  So I created one: import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
});

Comment: Adding the serializer did not affect the error, nor did changing store.find() to store.findRecord()

Comment: I got doubt in this attribute `person_id` , how are you defining it in model file ?. I know for JSON reponse server should return like `person-id` but i am not sure about the REST

Comment: Good point.  My model uses the underscore.  I'll investigate further.  Maybe I need a transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your backend is responding with underscore then you need to have the below code,

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  keyForAttribute: function(attr, method) {
    return Ember.String.underscore(attr);
  }
});
```

Comment: I've added that but no luck.  It appears that the serializer is not getting called (I set a breakpoint in it but it is never triggered.)  The only other thing I've discovered is that the Ember Inspector Data panel, shows "blogs" as having one record, with an ID of 14, but with all other attributes as "undefined".

Comment: Do you have model specific serializer ?

Comment: No.  Just the application serializer.

Comment: May be include all the relevant code in question that may give some hint, like adapter,serializer,model,route file

Comment: Here's the relevant code for retrieving "contacts" from the REST API (I'm using contacts, rather than blogs, since the table has only two fields (id, name).  I'll edit the question and add these there.

Comment: Hey your code looks perfect to me. only thing is your response should have  `Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8` . As this is the [code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/e44824cd97de7988ebd13ef31c7ac132993eec5d/addon/-private/system/store/finders.js#L133) ember throwing this assert. so here they are looking for array so may be your response is just string so its failed in that assertion

Comment: So the problem was related to CORS.  I had previously set up xdomain but for reasons I've not investigated something changed and it no longer worked when I came back to this project after a year's absence.  @kumkanillam, thanks your support, much appreciated.  Ember sure can be frustrating at times!